# Replace Spaces with Underscores in Uploaded File

Tags: php

I have a basic script that allows my site members to upload short samples of their compositions for customers to listen to.

Some file names have spaces which obviously causes problems when trying to play the samples. Is there a way to replace these spaces with underscores between uploading to the temp directory and moving the file to the 'samples' directory?

```
<?
            $url = "http://domain.com/uploads/samples/";
            //define the upload path
            $uploadpath = "/home/public_html/uploads/samples";
            //check if a file is uploaded
             if($_FILES['userfile']['name']) {
              $filename = trim(addslashes($_FILES['userfile']['name']));
            //move the file to final destination
              if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],
            $uploadpath."/". $filename)) {

              echo "

    bla bla bla, the final html output

            ";

              } else{
                if ($_FILES['userfile']['error'] > 0)
              {
                   switch ($_FILES['userfile']['error'])
                {
                  case 1:  echo 'File exceeded upload_max_filesize';  break;
                  case 2:  echo 'File exceeded max_file_size';  break;
                  case 3:  echo 'File only partially uploaded';  break;
                  case 4:  echo 'No file uploaded';  break;
                }
                exit;
              }
              }
            }
?>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After this line:

```
$filename = trim(addslashes($_FILES['userfile']['name']));
```

Write:

```
$filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $filename);
```

A filename like **hello  world.mp3** (two spaces) would come out as `hello__world.mp3` (two underscores), to avoid this you could do this instead:

```
$filename = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $filename);
```

Comment: `str_replace` is `(search, replace, subject)`.

Comment: will this work for single space in filename also $filename = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $filename);

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = str_replace(' ', '-', trim(addslashes($_FILES['userfile']['name'])));
```

Why `addslashes` though?  This also seems a little too simple -- am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

try;

```
$filename = trim(str_replace(" ","_", $_FILES['userfile']['name']));
```