# php move_uploaded_file not working when filename has spaces

Tags: php, file-upload

i am uploading a file to the server. everything works fine unless the uploaded file has a space in it.

I tried to use: 
    str_replace(" ", "_", $_FILES['image']['name']);

My code is

```
 $image_name= str_replace(" ", "_", $_FILES['image']['name']);
               $image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
               $image=$_FILES['image'];

              $url = "http://jkshahclasses.com/push_images/$image_name";
                if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name,"../../push_images/$image_name"))
                {
                    echo "file uploaded";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "error: file not uploaded";
                    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605896/replace-spaces-with-underscores-in-uploaded-file

Comment: Hi i added the trim to the image name before i replace spaces, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to slugify your file name before uploded :

```
  public function slugify($text)
  {
    // replace all non letters or digits by _
    $text = preg_replace('/\W+/', '_', $text);

    // trim and lowercase
    $text = strtolower(trim($text, '_'));

    return $text;
  }
```

But first you have to get only file name you can do it with this function :

```
$file_name = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

If you want to get file extension you have to use :

```
$file_ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesnt work. also somehow it renames the .jpg file to _jpg

Comment: Just to be clear, i should use this on the image file name not the temp name right? i used `$image_name = $this->slugify(pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'],PATHINFO_FILENAME)) . '.' . pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` but it still doesnt work